# Change specific element in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, element, associative-array

I have two associative arrays that can look as follows:

```
$prod1 = (
    [name] = 'John',
    [address] = 'Milky way',
    [city] = 'Miami',
);

$prod2 = (
    [address] = 'Not so milky way'
);
```

**$prod1** has always got the same kind of elements *(name, address, city)*, but **$prod2** could contain of either all of the elements or some of them

What I want is to replace the value in the elements in **$prod1** that matches with the elements in **$prod2**. In the example above **$prod2** contains of *address*, and therefore the address in **$prod1** should be replaced with the address in **$prod2** (the rest of the elements should of course stay as is).

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) function will do this for you:

```
$prod_new = array_merge($prod1, $prod2);
```

From [the documentation](http://php.net/array_merge):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.

Alternatively, you can use [the `+` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), which will give you the same result:

```
$prod_new = $prod1 + $prod2;
```

> The `+` operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($prod2 as $key => $val)
{
    $prod1[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
$prod1 = array(
name => 'John',
address => 'Milky way',
city => 'Miami',
);

$prod2 = array(
address => 'Not so milky way'
);

foreach ($prod2 as $key=>$value) {
$prod1[$value] = $value;
}
var_dump($prod1);
```

Enjoy :)